# Asus TP200SA Touchscreen and Touchpad problem

Tags: touchpad, asus, touchscreen

I have a Asus TP200SA Ubuntu on it (14.04 LTS)

When I installed (4 days ago) it the touchscreen and the touchpad worked flawlessly, I was very happy, but the rotation lock didn't (I was using it rarely so it wasn't a big deal). I've hosted server on it for about 8 hours, checking it semi-frequently. After a while, neither the touchscreen, nor the touchpad worked.
 I installed java and the wifi driver after installing ubuntu.

Now neither the touchpad, nor the touchscreen works, but the rotation lock does...

This is the xinput list:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]   
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]  
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]    
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

This is the lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:3491 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please do not write Solved etc. in the title. You accepted an answer, that is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it/ Worked alround it by installing Ubuntu 15.10. Sadly not LTS, but it atleast works! :D